# Mathematica collecting elements in a list

Tags: tuples, wolfram-mathematica, filtering, counting

Given the 256 tuples generated from:

```
Tuples[{a,b,c,d},4] = {{a,a,a,a},{a,a,a,b}...,{d,d,d,d}}
```

I would like to filter all of the tuples that have exactly 3 of a kind. For example, I want to keep {c,b,c,c} & {a,a,d,a} etc.. but not {d,d,d,d} or {a,b,b,c}.

I know there are:

```
Binomial[4,3]*4*3 = 48
```

such tuples from simple maths. But I am looking for a programmatic way of counting these.

My final goal is from the tuples:

```
Tuples[{1,2,3,...,n},k]
```

I would like to know how many of those tuples have exactly one subset with m of a kind, with all other subgroups of a kind having size less than m.

In case you are interested, this problem spawned from asking: What is the average number of rounds played before there is a winner in the game "**Cards Against Humanity**"? Assuming we have n players and the first person with x cards wins.

Comment: `Extract[#, {First[#]} & /@ Position[Tally /@ #, {_, 3}]] &@
 Tuples[{a, b, c, d}, 4]`  Do you know about [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will find your 48 tuples

```
Select[Tuples[{a, b, c, d}, 4], 
  MatchQ[Sort[#], {a_, a_, a_, b_} | {b_, a_, a_, a_}] && 
  Length[Union[#]] != 1 &]
```

This will show you the tuples of four items over 1,...,6 with m identical items and all other items appearing less than m times.

```
m = 2;
f[v_] := Module[{runlens},
  runlens = Sort[Map[Length, Split[Sort[v]]]]; 
  runlens[[-1]] == m && If[Length[runlens] == 1, True, runlens[[-2]] < m]]
];
Select[Tuples[Range[6], 4], f]
```

Use Count on that result and you know how many you have.

Comment: I somewhat see what you did, but it's still a little over my head. I want to take some time to  understand it better. At first I didn't think the MatchQ would pick up the case a_,b_,a_,a_ or a_,a_,b_a etc.. but it does.That being said, this is awesome! Thank you very much. You even went above and beyond to show how someone would go about tackling the problem in a more general case. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
Select[ Tuples[{a, b, c, d}, 4] ,
 ((Count[#, 3] == 1 && Max[#] == 3) &@Tally[#][[All, 2]] ) & ]
```

Of course if the set size is greater than half the list length it is redundant to check both `Max` and `Count`

Comment: You should consider doing an advanced Mathematica course on Udemy or something. I think it's hard to find good content like this and you might be filling a niche.